# Can Lorentz symmetry be broken?

Tags: special-relativity, cosmology, condensed-matter, symmetry-breaking

I am used to symmetry breaking in condensed matter, where we have a preferred reference frame (superconductivity, ferromagnets, etc). But what about Lorentz symmetry? What would such symmetry breaking look like? The intuition tells me the resulting system should look like a superfluid, where there is a continuum of ground states which can be transformed into one another by boosts, and the spectrum of excitation inside such superfluid does not have to be Lorentzian. Would this be a correct intuition?

Also, can it be we are living in a world with such broken Lorentz symmetry (since there is a preferred reference frame associated with CMB)?

Comment: Have you considered General Relativity?

Comment: As a comment, condensed matter systems can be understood as systems that spontaneously break Lorentz symmetry and the resulting Goldstone bosons are the phonons.

Comment: @FrodCube That looks like an answer, not a comment

Comment: @DanielC Considered in what sense? Do you mean that GR guaranties a preferred reference frame in an expanding universe? (I know a bit of GR, but it has been a while ago that I learned it)

Comment: @FrodCube Do you know any "condensed matter textbook/review article" that presents the theory ab initio within special relativity in covariant formulation and only then proves this "breaking of Lorentz symmetry" when treating ideal solid state (quantum) excitations?

Comment: @ACuriousMind I thought he wanted to know about a fundamental breaking of Lorentz in some UV completion of the Standard Model

Comment: @DanielC You can read the introduction (and references) of this for example: 1501.03845

Comment: @FrodCube That's illuminating, since I've always thought CMP assumes non-SR spacetime.

Comment: @DanielC sure, but Lorentz symmetry is always there, just "hidden" (i.e. non linearly realized)