# Does Lorentz symmetry breaking always require "stuff"?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, standard-model, symmetry-breaking

Following the thread ["can Lorentz symmetry be broken?"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/636335/) and the paper ["Zoology of condensed matter:
Framids, ordinary stuff, extra-ordinary stuff"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.03845), it appears that any system with Lorentz symmetry breaking is called a condensed matter system (with some extra details). For a condensed matter system we usually have to have "stuff" (atoms or fermions) to break the symmetry. **Question.** Can boost symmetry be broken without "stuff"?

Some extra questions. Why is Lorentz symmetry not broken in the Standard model? Is it possible that Lorentz symmetry is broken at higher energies?

Answer (score 1):

Lorentz symmetry is always broken, as a matter of fact, by **implied presence** of many reference systems (= stuff), between which we make the recalculation rules for observed results. Markers that break the Lorentz invariance are the relative distances between RFs, their relative orientations, their particular physical properties, etc., absent in the set of Lorentz transformations parameters.

Comment: It is a bit different symmetry breaking as compared to condensed matter systems though, since the Lorentz symmetry of the vacuum state is not broken. My question was rather, can we break the Lorenz symmetry of the ground state without presence of particles?