Can Lorentz invariance turn out to be an approximate symmetry in string theory?
I don't know whether I need to ask much but the essential question is at scales either approaching or at $M_{pl}$, can Lorentz invariance be broken? I am especially interested in the context of string theories, particularly $E_8$ but pretty much any string theory with such behavior is welcome.

Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/636335/2451

Lorentz violation within which theory/model?

@Qmechanic Probably in stringy models following the lines of $E_8$ string theory or really any string theory tbh.
